# Bringing front a user control by a button which is located in another user control

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have a scenario (Windows Forms, C#, .NET):

1. There is a main form which hosts 2 user controls named `us1` and `us2`.
2. There is a button called `btnDisplay`inside `us1`.
3. Only `us1` is visible, because I have brought it to front.
4. When user clicks on `btnDisplay`, `us2` must come to front but I don't have any controls on `us2` inside `us1.cs`!

How should I implement this?

Comment: You have to check which control is in the back and bring it to front. I believe you are looking for GetChildIndex which will tell you if the control in front or not. But how would you send it to back again if you don't have any controls in us2?

Comment: @kaj I need an event handler to declare the us2 inside us1 but i don't know how to do this!

Comment: Ok I got it, can't you take an instance from us2 in us1?

Comment: If you simulate this scenario, you will see that you can not access us2 from btnDisplay which is located in us1. This accessability is problem...! @kaj

Comment: @kaj I don't understand... can't you provide an script that btnDisplay brings us2 to front? All I need is this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options I'd consider.

1) The first option would be to change the modifier of btnDisplay to be `internal` or `public` instead of `private`.

[image: Changing btnDisplay modifier]

This allows you to subscribe to the click event in your form.  When the click event is fired you simply bring the other control to the front.

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  us11.btnDisplay.Click += BtnDisplay_Click;
}

private void us11_DisplayButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  us21.BringToFront();
}
```

2) The other option would be to pass your us2 control to the us1 control so the us1 control can bring us2 to the front.

```
public partial class us1 : UserControl
{
    // Property to hold the us2 control.
    public us2 us2 { get; set; }

    public us1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Bring the other control to the front if the property has been set.
        us2?.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

In your form set the us2 property on us1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        us11.us2 = us21;
    }

}
```

I'd probably go with option 2 if it makes sense for us1 to "know" about the other control.  If it makes more sense for the form to know about the button being clicked, and then to do something, then option 1 might be better.

Comment: for option 2 I get this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object!

Comment: Where do you get that exception?  Are you setting the us1.us2 property in the constructor of your form?

Comment: It worked thanks, I just missed setting the property of us2 on us1.

Comment: The question mark in the `us2?.BringToFront();` call will make it so it won't try to call the function if the `us1` property isn't set.

Comment: can you please explain what happens when we set the us2 property on us1? I mean, can you provide a theoretical explanation..?

Comment: It's probably easiest to understand by reading a little about properties, http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/csharpclassproperties.aspx. Also the names of your classes probably don't help to explain the concept since they're very generic.