# BringToFront() UserControl1 from UserControl2

Tags: c#, winforms

Both User Control is in my main form. UserControl2 is a 
of the main form and UserControl1 is one of the tabs of UserControl2.
[image: sub-menu]

I've set the identifier of UserControl1 to **public** in the main form, and added this in one of the buttons of my UserControl2:

```
private void btnProducts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmMain main = new frmMain();        //Main Form
        main.products1.BringToFront();       //UserControl1 in Main Form
    }
```

I'm doing this Windows Forms App, by the way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you specify what exactly is the problem you need to solve? Pls post any errors or exceptions that you may be getting

Comment: This => `frmMain main = new frmMain();` will create a new instance of the same `Form` your UCs are part of. This => `main.products1.BringToFront();` will try to change *something* in this new instance. The result, in the original `frmMain`, is mute. If UC1 is part of UC2, then UC2 should know how to *BringToFront* one of it's components parts. Maybe, UC1 told it how (specific public events, properties, methods). Not the Form that contains them.

Comment: UC1 is doing it right, it raises the Click event to let other code figure out what to do with the click.  UC2 is not, it is trying to do too much and that is getting you in trouble.  Imagine you also want to use it on another form for example.  Just do it the same way as UC1, raise your own ItemClicked event.

Comment: How would I be able to BringToFront() UC1 if they are both in the same form?

Comment: Solved, I tried [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50927992/bringing-front-a-user-control-by-a-button-which-is-located-in-another-user-contr?rq=1).